# Importing Python module from another directory

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-3.6

I have a python program which has the following project structure:

```
ProjectName
     |
     |----ProjectMain.py
     |
     |----__init__.py
     |
     |----Common
            |
            |----Dictionaries
            |         |
            |         |----Dicts.py
            |         |
            |         |----__init__.py
            |
            |----Core.py
            |
            |----LogoCreator.py
            |
            |----__init__.py
```

The contents of each file, apart from every `__init__.py` files which are all empty, are the following:

LogoCreator.py

```
def random_logo():
#    do stuff
```

Core.py

```
from LogoCreator import random_logo
import Dictionaries.Dicts as Dicts

#do stuff
```

Dicts.py

```
i_am_a_dictionary = {}
```

ProjectMain.py

```
from Common.Core import *
import Common.Dictionaries.Dicts as Dicts

#do stuff
```

When i run ProjectMain.py, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ProjectName\ProjectMain.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Common.Core import *
  File "ProjectName\Common\Core.py", line 1, in <module>
    from LogoCreator import random_logo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'LogoCreator'
```

This is the first i work with packages, so any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: In your Core.py, replace `from LogoCreator import random_logo` with `from Common.LogoCreator import random_logo`. Replace  `import Dictionaries.Dicts as Dicts` with `import Common.Dictionaries.Dicts as Dicts`. And try to run with command `python -m ProjectName.ProjectMain`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the method random_logo, you must use the dot notation once you import LogoCreator.

```
from Common import LogoCreator
def create (self):
  x = self.random_logo()
  #code that generates a random logo
```